# sql syntax error in vba to filter a combobox

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I need to filter the available options of a combobox according to the IDKey of the current record [AllocID]

After unsuccessfullly trying various versions of WHERE clauses directly in the Rowsource of the combobox, I came across a solution suggesting I set the rowsource in the On Current event of the form:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
MSMgeID.RowSource = "SELECT[MSMge].[PrjID] ... FROM MSMge WHERE [PrjID] ='" & Me.AllocID & " '"
End Sub
```

Both [PrjID] and [AllocID] are numeric fields of Long Integer type but I'm getting a "Data Mismatch in criteria expression".

Is there something I'm doing in my SQL syntax that's confusing one of the fields as text?

Comment: what's the error message you are getting?

Comment: The error message I'm getting is "Data Mismatch in criteria expression"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
MSMgeID.RowSource = "SELECT [MSMge].[PrjID] ... FROM MSMge WHERE [PrjID] =" & CStr(Me.AllocID)
```

Here is an explanation:

Both [MSMge].[PrjID] and Me.AllocID are numeric values, as OP said. So, instead of using `Where [PrjID] = '<some value>'` (which will trigger the type mismatch error in Access) we need to instead cast `Me.AllocID` in VB code to string using the `CStr()` function. The statement above will be translated to `Where [PrjID] = <some numeric value>` (note that I have dropped the single apostrophes)

Comment: It works! I have no idea why, it's the last thing I'd have thought to try, but it works! I guess [PrjID] is being read as text for some reason (i.e. my code error) but anyway, thank you so much.